# How can I create a good sprites for my app?

Tags: drawing, 2d

I have someone that draws everything for me. He is actually drawing it and not using any program... it turns out all right but I have a problem. It looks just like someone drew it and not "real" or "high level of drawing".

Anyways, I want to take the sprite that he made and make it look "lifelike". For example look at the game "sprinkle" (link below), the character in there looks not drawn, I mean like it looks like its 3d but not 3d. I hope that you understand me..

Thanks!

```
(https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mediocre.sprinkle&feature=banner#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIwMSwiY29tLm1lZGlvY3JlLnNwcmlua2xlIl0.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenarios and assets of that game are pretty impressive.
The options you do have:

- Model 3D and render as 2D (3dStudioMax and Blender are recommended for games);
- Scan draws, stroke with digital tool (Photoshop, Gimp) and use painter skill to it looks like vivid as you want.

Comment: Thanks i'm going to try these

Comment: Yes, it's. Professional tool for 3d modelling, high level as biggest studios as Pixar, Dreamworks, and game industry.

Comment: I made my character there in 3d and used some spheres and everything. how do i render it as a 2d pic?

Comment: Try to search on Google about alpha rendering. You'll render a frame and keep your alpha channel. Or, you'll need use a solid color for background and your API will be responsible for apply some color key/chroma key skill. How to render will depend which software you're using. Read about TGA, GIF or PNG, you'll get something about those transparent, 32 bits and things like that.